# Search function is not working after includeing the pagination

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pagination

i am having serach function which word before after implemrnting the pagination the search function is not working ,can any one tell me where i am wrong and how to search makes work

my php code with pagination

```
<?php


  $tbl_name="contact";       //your table name
    $adjacents = 7;

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];




    $targetpage = "filterdata.php";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
    $limit = 10;    
    //how many items to show per page

   $page = $_GET['page'];
        if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
    else
        $start = 0;                           //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    /* Get data. */
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT contact.`id` , contact.`contactgroup` , contact.`media` ,contact.`media2` , contact.`email1` , contact.`nationality` , contact.`country3` , contact.`twon` , contact.`area` , contact.`gender` , contact.`married` , contact.`children` , contact.`driverslicense` FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";
    print $sql;

    $result1 = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($language !="" && $language !="Empty" ){



                $language_exp = explode(',', $language);
     $sql .= " INNER JOIN contactlanguage ON contact.id = contactlanguage.contactid
INNER JOIN language ON contactlanguage.languageid = language.id where isdeleted = 0 AND language.language in ('".implode("', '", $language_exp)."') "; 

            }else{

                $sql .= " where isdeleted = 0";
            }


    if ($contactgroup !="" && $contactgroup !="Empty" ){



    $contactgroup_exp = explode(',', $contactgroup);
    $sql .= " AND contactgroup in ('".implode("', '", $contactgroup_exp)."')";

    }

     if ($media !="" && $media !="Empty" && $media == "sms" ){
                      $sql.=" and media = '".$media."'";     

            }

             if ($media !="" && $media !="Empty" && $media == "email" ){
                      $sql.=" and media2 = '".$media."'";     

            }

             if ($media !="" && $media !="Empty" && $media == "sms,email" ){
                      $sql.=" and media = 'sms' and media2 = 'email' ";     

            }


             if ($nationality !="" && $nationality !="Empty" ){
                     $nationality_exp = explode(',', $nationality);
     $sql .= " AND nationality in ('".implode("', '", $nationality_exp)."')";  

            }

             if ($country !="" && $country !="Empty" ){
                      $country_exp = explode(',', $country);
     $sql .= " AND country1 in ('".implode("', '", $country_exp)."')";     

            }

            if ($twon !="" && $twon !="Empty" ){
                      $city_exp = explode(',', $twon);
     $sql .= " AND twon in ('".implode("', '", $city_exp)."')";   

            }

             if ($area !="" && $area !="Empty" ){
                        $area_exp = explode(',', $area);
     $sql .= " AND area in ('".implode("', '", $area_exp)."')";       

            }

             if ($gender !="" && $gender !="Empty" && $gender !="all" ){
                      $sql.=" and gender = '".$gender."'";     

            }

             if ($gender =="all" ){
                      $sql.=" AND (`gender` = 'female' OR `gender` = 'male' OR `gender` = '') ";     

            }

            if ($married !="" && $married !="Empty" && $married !="all" ){
                      $sql.=" and married = '".$married."'";     

            }

             if ($married =="all" ){
                      $sql.=" AND (`married` = 'yes' OR `married` = 'no' OR `married` = '') ";     

            }

            if ($children !="" && $children !="Empty" && $children !="all" ){
                      $sql.=" and children = '".$children."'";     

            }

             if ($children =="all" ){
                      $sql.=" AND (`children` = 'yes' OR `children` = 'no' OR `children` = '') ";     

            }
            if ($driver !="" && $driver !="Empty" && $driver !="all" ){
                      $sql.=" and driverslicense = '".$driver."'";     

            }

             if ($driver =="all" ){
                      $sql.=" AND (`driverslicense` = 'yes' OR `driverslicense` = 'no' OR `driverslicense` = '') ";     

            }



             if ($retype !="" && $retype !="Empty" && $retype !="all" ){
                      $sql.=" and retype = '".$retype."'";     

            }


             if ($retype =="all" ){
                      $sql.=" AND (`retype` = 'apart' OR `retype` = 'house' OR `retype` = '') ";     

            }
             if ($restatus !="" && $restatus !="Empty" && $restatus !="all" ){
                      $sql.=" and restatus = '".$restatus."'";     

            }

             if ($restatus =="all" ){
                      $sql.=" AND (`restatus` = 'owner' OR `restatus` = 'renting' OR `restatus` = '') ";     

            }

            if ($reproject !="" && $reproject !="Empty" ){

                    $reproject_exp = explode(',', $reproject);
     $sql .= " AND reproject1 in ('".implode("', '", $reproject_exp)."')";    



            }

                if ($education !="" && $education !="Empty" ){

                    $education_exp = explode(',', $education);
     $sql .= " AND education in ('".implode("', '", $education_exp)."')";    



            }

                if ($jobrole !="" && $jobrole !="Empty" ){


                    $jobrole_exp = explode(',', $jobrole);
     $sql .= " AND jobrole in ('".implode("', '", $jobrole_exp)."')";   



            }

                if ($jobsector !="" && $jobsector !="Empty" ){


                    $jobsector_exp = explode(',', $jobsector);
     $sql .= " AND jobsector in ('".implode("', '", $jobsector_exp)."')";   



            }

             if ($dataperiod !="" && $dataperiod !="EmptyEmptyEmpty" && $arraydataperiodcount !="EmptyEmpty" && $arraydataperiodcount !="" && $dataperiod !="EmptyEmpty"){
                      $sql.=" and dataperiod BETWEEN $arraydataperiodcount[0] AND $arraydataperiodcount[1] ";     

            }

             if ($age !="" && $age !="Empty" ){
                      $sql.=" and age BETWEEN $agebetween[0] AND $agebetween[1] ";     

            }


    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                    //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    //print $lastpage; 
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\"> previous</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\"> previous</span>"; 

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))    //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)) //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))     
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next </a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next </span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";     
    }


//echo $sql;




//print $sql;




while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{

           echo '<tr>';



echo ' 


        <td class="edit contactgroup '.$rows["id"].'" >'.$rows["contactgroup"].'</td>';


            if($media == "sms"){
echo' <td class="edit media '.$rows["id"].'" >'.$rows["media"].'</td>';
}
else if($media == "email"){
echo' <td class="edit media '.$rows["id"].'" >'.$rows["media2"].'</td>';
}else{

    echo' <td class="edit media '.$rows["id"].'" >'.$rows["media"].'</td>';
}   




     echo ' <td class="edit email '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["email1"].'</td>
            <td class="edit nationality '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["nationality"].'</td>   
            <td class="edit country '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["country3"].'</td>
            <td class="edit twon '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["twon"].'</td>    
<td class="edit area '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["area"].'</td>            
  <td class="edit gender '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["gender"].'</td>                  
     <td class="edit married '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["married"].'</td>             
      <td class="edit children '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["children"].'</td> 
      <td class="edit driverlicense '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["driverslicense"].'</td>       

        </tr>';


}



?>

<?php echo $pagination; ?>
```

my html code for search

```
<div class="controls" style=" margin:10px -45px 10px 1px">
                                            <button type="submit" style="margin:0px" class="filtercontact">Search</button>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: less code more answers, its sure that i am not going to read this

Comment: You initialise your SQL, placing the limit clause at the end of it. You then append various WHERE clauses on the end (AFTER the limit clause), but you execute the sql before adding the clauses. With where the mysql_query is the limit for pagination should work by the clauses are ignored. If it is put after the clauses are set up the SQL will be invalid

Comment: can you write it for me it will helpful for me to understand thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick attempt at changing your code (not tested). Reformatted a bit as well.

This is initialising the sql, then adding the WHERE clauses (and possibly the join), then adding the limit clause before executing it

```
<?php


  $tbl_name="contact";       //your table name
    $adjacents = 7;

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

    $targetpage = "filterdata.php";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
    $limit = 10;    
    //how many items to show per page

    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
    else
        $start = 0;                           //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    /* Get data. */
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT contact.`id` , contact.`contactgroup` , contact.`media` ,contact.`media2` , contact.`email1` , contact.`nationality` , contact.`country3` , contact.`twon` , contact.`area` , contact.`gender` , contact.`married` , contact.`children` , contact.`driverslicense` 
            FROM $tbl_name ";
    if ($language !="" && $language !="Empty" )
    {
        $language_exp = explode(',', $language);
        $sql .= " INNER JOIN contactlanguage ON contact.id = contactlanguage.contactid
        INNER JOIN language ON contactlanguage.languageid = language.id where isdeleted = 0 AND language.language in ('".implode("', '", $language_exp)."') "; 
    }
    else
    {
        $sql .= " where isdeleted = 0";
    }
    if ($contactgroup !="" && $contactgroup !="Empty" )
    {
        $contactgroup_exp = explode(',', $contactgroup);
        $sql .= " AND contactgroup in ('".implode("', '", $contactgroup_exp)."')";
    }

    if ($media !="" && $media !="Empty" && $media == "sms" )
    {
        $sql.=" and media = '".$media."'";     
    }

    if ($media !="" && $media !="Empty" && $media == "email" )
    {
        $sql.=" and media2 = '".$media."'";     
    }
    if ($media !="" && $media !="Empty" && $media == "sms,email" )
    {
        $sql.=" and media = 'sms' and media2 = 'email' ";     
    }
    if ($nationality !="" && $nationality !="Empty" )
    {
        $nationality_exp = explode(',', $nationality);
        $sql .= " AND nationality in ('".implode("', '", $nationality_exp)."')";  
    }
    if ($country !="" && $country !="Empty" )
    {
        $country_exp = explode(',', $country);
        $sql .= " AND country1 in ('".implode("', '", $country_exp)."')";     
    }
    if ($twon !="" && $twon !="Empty" )
    {
        $city_exp = explode(',', $twon);
        $sql .= " AND twon in ('".implode("', '", $city_exp)."')";   
    }
    if ($area !="" && $area !="Empty" )
    {
        $area_exp = explode(',', $area);
        $sql .= " AND area in ('".implode("', '", $area_exp)."')";       
    }
    if ($gender !="" && $gender !="Empty" && $gender !="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" and gender = '".$gender."'";     
    }
    if ($gender =="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" AND (`gender` = 'female' OR `gender` = 'male' OR `gender` = '') ";     
    }
    if ($married !="" && $married !="Empty" && $married !="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" and married = '".$married."'";     
    }
    if ($married =="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" AND (`married` = 'yes' OR `married` = 'no' OR `married` = '') ";     
    }
    if ($children !="" && $children !="Empty" && $children !="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" and children = '".$children."'";     
    }
    if ($children =="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" AND (`children` = 'yes' OR `children` = 'no' OR `children` = '') ";     
    }
    if ($driver !="" && $driver !="Empty" && $driver !="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" and driverslicense = '".$driver."'";     
    }
    if ($driver =="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" AND (`driverslicense` = 'yes' OR `driverslicense` = 'no' OR `driverslicense` = '') ";     
    }
    if ($retype !="" && $retype !="Empty" && $retype !="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" and retype = '".$retype."'";     
    }
    if ($retype =="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" AND (`retype` = 'apart' OR `retype` = 'house' OR `retype` = '') ";     
    }
    if ($restatus !="" && $restatus !="Empty" && $restatus !="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" and restatus = '".$restatus."'";     
    }
    if ($restatus =="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" AND (`restatus` = 'owner' OR `restatus` = 'renting' OR `restatus` = '') ";     
    }

    if ($reproject !="" && $reproject !="Empty" )
    {
        $reproject_exp = explode(',', $reproject);
        $sql .= " AND reproject1 in ('".implode("', '", $reproject_exp)."')";    
    }

    if ($education !="" && $education !="Empty" )
    {
        $education_exp = explode(',', $education);
        $sql .= " AND education in ('".implode("', '", $education_exp)."')";    
    }

    if ($jobrole !="" && $jobrole !="Empty" )
    {
        $jobrole_exp = explode(',', $jobrole);
        $sql .= " AND jobrole in ('".implode("', '", $jobrole_exp)."')";   
    }

    if ($jobsector !="" && $jobsector !="Empty" )
    {
        $jobsector_exp = explode(',', $jobsector);
        $sql .= " AND jobsector in ('".implode("', '", $jobsector_exp)."')";   
    }

    if ($dataperiod !="" && $dataperiod !="EmptyEmptyEmpty" && $arraydataperiodcount !="EmptyEmpty" && $arraydataperiodcount !="" && $dataperiod !="EmptyEmpty")
    {
        $sql.=" and dataperiod BETWEEN $arraydataperiodcount[0] AND $arraydataperiodcount[1] ";     
    }

    if ($age !="" && $age !="Empty" )
    {
        $sql.=" and age BETWEEN $agebetween[0] AND $agebetween[1] "; 
    }

    $sql.="LIMIT $start, $limit";

    print $sql;

    $result1 = mysql_query($sql);

    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                    //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    //print $lastpage; 
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\"> previous</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\"> previous</span>"; 

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))    //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)) //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))     
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next </a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next </span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";     
    }


//echo $sql;
//print $sql;

while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '  <td class="edit contactgroup '.$rows["id"].'" >'.$rows["contactgroup"].'</td>';

    if($media == "sms")
    {
        echo' <td class="edit media '.$rows["id"].'" >'.$rows["media"].'</td>';
    }
    else if($media == "email")
    {
        echo' <td class="edit media '.$rows["id"].'" >'.$rows["media2"].'</td>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo' <td class="edit media '.$rows["id"].'" >'.$rows["media"].'</td>';
    }   
         echo ' <td class="edit email '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["email1"].'</td>
                <td class="edit nationality '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["nationality"].'</td>   
                <td class="edit country '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["country3"].'</td>
                <td class="edit twon '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["twon"].'</td>    
    <td class="edit area '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["area"].'</td>            
      <td class="edit gender '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["gender"].'</td>                  
         <td class="edit married '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["married"].'</td>             
          <td class="edit children '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["children"].'</td> 
          <td class="edit driverlicense '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["driverslicense"].'</td>       

            </tr>';
}

?>

<?php echo $pagination; ?>
```